# Gnome not starting using latest 5.9.8 kernel

Tags: fedora, gnome

After updating to the latest kernel (**5.9.8-200**) on **fedora 33** gnome doesn't start anymore (using older **5.8.18** kernel gnome does indeed start).

Output of *[journalctl -b -1 -p 5](https://pastebin.com/bSshTtZk)*

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your log:

```
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2835]: (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2835]: (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2835]: (EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2835]: (EE) No devices detected.
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2835]: (EE)
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2835]: Fatal server error:
/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2835]: (EE) no screens found(EE)
```

NVIDIA drivers are currently not compatible with kernel 5.9. Please use 5.8 and keep your eye on https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

From https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-not-yet-supported-for-linux-kernel-5-9/157260

> Due to an incompatibility issue, we advise customers to defer updating to Linux Kernel 5.9+ until mid-November when an NVIDIA Linux GPU driver update with Kernel 5.9+ support is expected to be available.

> Linux Kernel 5.9+ is incompatible with current and previous NVIDIA Linux GPU drivers. We advise customers to defer updating to Linux Kernel 5.9+ until mid-November when an NVIDIA Linux GPU driver update with Kernel 5.9+ support is expected to be available. NVIDIA is aware of the impact this will have on customers, and we are working diligently to provide the driver update with Kernel 5.9+ support as soon as possible.

> Customers must use our upcoming driver update on Kernel 5.9+ to have a fully functioning driver.